# Use single user in multiple orgs in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a scenario here, in which I want to register and enrol a user which can be used in multiple organisations. But I cannot get any way to do so. Does anyone have any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my issue. I came across something called Organisational Units in the Fabric CA. We can have multiple intermediate CAs for multiple organisational units and one root CAs. Each Organisational Unit will act as an individual Org and the user registered and enrolled by root CA can access chaincodes in any of the Organisational Units.